# HTML5 Multi Track Sync Video Audio on IOS

Tags: html, audio, video, synchronization

I'm looking for a way to multitrack a video with a bunch of sounds.

IOS prevent multiple audio and video to play at the same time.
I found a way on IOS, to launch a sound and an audio by putting the video.play() command in a setTimout (500ms). But this don't works every time, and the medias are not sync. This is not code consistent and maybe apple will correct this on breach on next version of iOS

MediaGroup and MediaController seem supported on iOS but not work properly.
AudioTrack was implemented on some navigators and seem to be removed

What is the alternative?

I've already tried those:

//gingertech.net/2011/05/01/html5-multi-track-audio-or-video/
//blog.denivip.ru/index.php/2013/10/alternative-audio-tracks-in-html5-video/?lang=en
//ldki.blogspot.ca/2012/11/15-html5-video-player-sync-second-audio.html